# Trying to Free Up Space - Can I Delete Library Cache?

Tags: macos, storage, disk-space, adobe, library

I'm trying to figure out how to free up some space on my MacBook. I downloaded Disk Inventory X, and in looking at the storage breakdown it provides, I see that my Library folder is 119.4 GB. Library > Caches inside there has 96.7 GB. Caches > Adobe has 93.1 GB. Looks like After Effects is taking up the most space in there with 92 GB. That seems like an insane amount of space for one program cache.

Also, Library > Application Support has 21.8 GB. And Application Support > Adobe has 20.2 GB.

What can I delete without messing up my computer? I use the Adobe Suite pretty much every day, so I don't want to screw it up.

Comment: Leave Application Support alone. The caches should be transient, meaning they should be able to be deleted without issue, but I would move it to another drive (preferably external) and run Adobe After Effects and see if there are any negative consequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can delete anything in the Cache folder. There's no unsaved things. Just cached data. Like renderinged things in the case of After Effects.

In video editing software you can often define maximum cache size.