# Cannot Update Apps on MacOS App Store

Tags: software-update, macos

When I try to update an app, and I go to the 'Updates' page, I Get this error in a dialogue box:

`Could not load data from the Apple software update server.`

I checked my Internet connection, everything is fine.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how long this has been happening for? Does the App Store app indicate you have any updates? And have you tried logging out of your account and logging back in?

Comment: Tried everything

Comment: Please check I've added Step 4.

Comment: Try close App Store, then open Apple Menu  -> About This Mac -> Software Update…

Comment: Have you tried deleting "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist", restarting your Mac and then trying again?

Answer (score 6):

Please backup all your data. Example: with Time Machine or similar Software (if you not use Time Machine).

All steps are complete in itself. If any of these works you don't need the other steps.

**Step 1:** Appstore

1. Open the Appstore and choose from the Menu Store the option to show your Account. You need your AppleID password to access to your account.
2. If you have access to your account, click on the button **reset all warnings**.
3. Log out from the Appstore and close the app. Start Appstore again
4. Log in to your AppleID by using the option from the Store menu.
5. Test if the update process works.

**Step 2:** Using Terminal

1. Open your Terminal. Choosing from the Finder Menu **Go To..** the Option **Utilities**. Start the Terminal.app
2. Type or insert the following command in your Terminal and hit Enter.

   ```
   softwareupdate -i -a
   ```

If this not work or you got an error use the following command.

```
    sudo softwareupdate -i -a
```

Test whether AppStore updates work.

**Step 3:** The Hard Way

*Reset PRAM*
To Reset PRAM, restart the Mac and hold the keys <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Option (Alt)</kbd>+P+R simultaneously during startup. Hold down the keys until you hear the second sound output.

*Move the following files to the trash or on your Desktop. Close the AppStore before using the following instructions.*

1. Click on the Finder Desktop and press the keys <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+G.
2. Insert the following Line in the window and press **Enter**.

   `~/Library/Preferences/`

Delete the following files (if exists)

**com.apple.appstore.plist**
**com.apple.storeagent.plist**

3. Restart your mac and test if works.

**Step 4:** Use Debug menu

1. Close App Store with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+Q
2. Open Terminal and insert the following Command:

   `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true`
3. Open App Store and choose from the Debug Menu **Show download Folder**
4. Close App Store and move the Download folder to the trash.
5. Restart your mac (this is important), empty the trash and try if app store works.

Comment: Nope. tried all three, but none of them work :( . I did not have com.apple.appstore.plist and com.apple.storeagent.plist.

Comment: Added Step 4 check whether it works.

Comment: Don't get any debug menu :(. Is it on the bar where it says 'App Store    Edit    Store'?  Where else can it be?

Comment: This is an extra menu next to the help menu. If you insert the following command in the Terminal do you receive any output? `defaults read com.apple.appstore`

Comment: yes. I get an output. it is too long to post as a comment. see it on github here: https://github.com/suryanisaac/Errors/blob/master/OutputFordefaults-read-com.apple.appstore

Comment: It's the same output as mine, but I don't understand that you cannot see it. If you open the App Store on the top of your screen next to the help menu should be the Debug menu.

Comment: ScreenShot: https://github.com/suryanisaac/Errors/blob/master/Pasted%20Graphic%201.tiff

Comment: Ok try following: Type in terminal: `open $TMPDIR../C/` and delete the **com.apple.appstore** folder. Restart, empty trash and open AppStore.

Comment: Nope Does not work :( . I am waiting for 22nd to update to the stable version. (It is releasing in india on 22nd)

Comment: Sorry, my options goes to the end. You can try the suggestions from @sfaruque and but I think this will not solve the problem. The only that I still think that the App may be corrupt. If you have an earlier backup, rename the current app and move the earlier backup to the app-folder.

Answer (score 3):

A similar experience happened to me a few months back. I fixed it by clearing the Caches folder:

1. Go to: ~/Library/Caches
2. Move everything here to the Trash
3. Empty the trash.
4. Restart your Mac

Clearing the Cache folder is perfectly safe.

Reference: [Trying to Free Up Space - Can I Delete Library Cache?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186017/trying-to-free-up-space-can-i-delete-library-cache)

Comment: Sorry, Does not work :(.

Answer (score 3):

**It could be hosts issues**

Make sure your `/etc/hosts` file looks like something like this:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Remove any `gs.apple.com` entries.

See: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201442

**It could be dns issues**

Maybe you have inappropriate DNS configured.

Recommended:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

See: http://osxdaily.com/2015/12/05/change-dns-server-settings-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253284/279727) resolved the issue in my case. I had this entry in the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 osxapps.itunes.apple.com
```

I was able to download updates after removing the entry without doing a system restart.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It transpires that I had moved from Australia to the UK and the apps that were causing the issue were installed when I was in Australia.

To solve the issue I had to logout from my UK AppStore Account and logon using my Australian AppStore account. Once I did this and chose to update the apps it all worked.

Oh, make sure you logout of the old Appstore account and back in with your current region's account when finished.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the command that resolved this was:

```
sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog
```

(Found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/221419/238906)